# How do i feature blog posts in featured areas of my Wordpress blog homepage?

Tags: wordpress

Forgive the newbie question but i'm starting up a new blog using wordpress and, having installed a template and begun the very initial steps of setting it up, i've got an issue with not being able to configure the 'featured areas' to be able to pull in the blog posts.

The URL is http://theformula1blog.com/

Have looked around and tried to configure this way but not been able to get it to work. Ideally i'd have the most three recent posts in the featured areas and then potentially a couple more below them.

Any tip would be appreciated as i start to play with WP and get to grips with configuring it.

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about programming.  Perhaps you should look at [sf] instead, though check for duplicates there before asking again.

Comment: I suggest asking on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ - seems more appropriate for them

Comment: @CalvT Thanks for the heads up. Will take a look there. Cheers

Comment: What theme did you use? Ask on their support channel.

Comment: @ExecuKev make sure you read this before asking, so you don't get downvoted on that site too - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Also this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can make blog post as featured from admin area, So in database post's flag will be set as featured. Now on home page template you can add where condition for featured flag.